# Scheduling a monthly event "Every Nth Weekday" using RFC 5545 recurrence rule

Tags: c#, time, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm trying to replicate some scheduling functionality in Google Calendar in C# using the RFC5545 recurrence rule.

There are two options for scheduling monthly with Google calendar, either by every Nth day month, ie: **Every 10th day of the month every 1 months**, this will obviously occur regardless of the week day.

My recurrence rule for this is: `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=10`

The other option is to repeat the event on every Nth weekday, ie: "**Every second Sunday every one months**, this is the one I'm having trouble writing the rule for.

What should my rule be for the second rule? I've tried `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=SU`, but I'm unsure how/which parameters to use to specify to only do this every 2nd Sunday of the month.

I'm using the *DDay iCal* C# library to generate my recurrence rule, but I'm happy to just be shown what the rule string should look like to achieve the desired behavior.

I'm using the [RFC 5545 recurrence rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there. What you need is to set the index for the day, RFC5545 says:

> Each BYDAY value can also be preceded by a positive (+n) or
>         negative (-n) integer.  If present, this indicates the nth
>         occurrence of a specific day within the MONTHLY or YEARLY "RRULE".

for which RFC5545 later gives an example

> Monthly on the first Friday for 10 occurrences:

```
   DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970905T090000
   RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=10;BYDAY=1FR
```

so for you the rule has to be:

`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=2SU`