# Scheduling a monthly event “Every Nth Weekday or Weekend Day” using RFC 5545 recurrence rule

Tags: office365, rfc5545

I've found similar [question name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050521/scheduling-a-monthly-event-every-nth-weekday-using-rfc-5545-recurrence-rule), but it is a little different.

Office365 UI interface can provide recurring rule where `repeat: monthly On second weekday` or `repeat: monthly On third weekend day`

How I could represent `second weekday` and `third weekend day` using [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- monthly on second weekday:

  FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=2

  This rule expands to every weekday of each month, but in the end selects only the 2nd day of the set.

  See the expanded result: http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20170602T000000&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BBYDAY%3DMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%3BBYSETPOS%3D2&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000101T000000&strict=1
- monthly on third weekend day

  FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=SA,SU;BYSETPOS=3

  This rule expands to every weekend day of each month, but in the end selects only the 3rd result of the set.

  See the expanded result: http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20170610T000000&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BBYDAY%3DSA%2CSU%3BBYSETPOS%3D3&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000101T000000&strict=1